# Java model best practices SQL - JSON -VIEW

Tags: java, model

While working on a Java web application I was wondering if my model layer was written as it should be. For instance, let's say we have a table USER in our SQL database which consists of 15 columns. Now, when we SELECT all of the columns with SQL we map it to a Java class, serialize via JSON and send it via network to some View and show it on screen.

In a second scenario, we want to select only 2 columns on screen so we do SELECT c1,c2 FROM USER. Thats where my question comes in... am I supposed to map those columns to a same Java model class? Or should i create a new mapper and class to fit it? Both of the approaches seem to have drawbacks, separate class for each query is more work, but it makes sure you always know what data it contains, rather than checking for nulls or working with optionals, also it prevents you from mapping columns you actually don't need.

What is your opinion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Though it is more code and thus more work to do, using one class for different mappings of sql data is an architectural no-go. You would have to leave class members uninitialized or explicitly set them to `null`. Check out the Single Responsibility Principle of the SOLID architecture principles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could reuse the same `User` class for full 15-attribute as well as partial 2-attribute entity. But that will come with a price. Every time you'll see an instance of `User` class in the code your will have to think if it's the full entity or the partial? Which fields may or may not be null? This will make it much harder to reason about code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about naming? How would you name it? For instance User with only 2 columns; username and display name? It's not a User anymore it's like UserWithUsernameAndDisplayName but that would be too long ofcourse...

Comment: Oh, naming is hard. `UserDetails`, `UserNameDetails`, `UserNameInfo`.